# IF sentence in a FOR loop throughout a dataframe: performance improvement

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, if-statement

I'm using an if statement inside a for loop throughout a pandas datafame, but it is taking too long to process. Is there a way to do this without the for loop?

```
for i in data.index:
    if data['qt_CNAE'][i] > 20:
        data['CNAEuse'][i]=data['CNAE'][i]
        data['CNAEuse_Cres'][i]=data['Crescimento_CNAE'][i]
```

Comment: Can you add data sample, 5 rows with expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need double [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
mask = data['qt_CNAE'] > 20
data['CNAEuse']= np.where(mask, data['CNAE'], data['CNAEuse'])
data['CNAEuse_Cres']=np.where(mask, data['Crescimento_CNAE'], data['CNAEuse_Cres'])
```

Or better with `numpy broadcasting`:

```
mask = data['qt_CNAE'] > 20
df[['CNAEuse','CNAEuse_Cres']] =(np.where(mask[:, None],
                                          df[['CNAE','Crescimento_CNAE']], 
                                          df[['CNAEuse','CNAEuse_Cres']]))
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                   'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'F':list('aaabbb')})

print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  a  4  7  1  5  a
1  b  5  8  3  3  a
2  c  4  9  5  6  a
3  d  5  4  7  9  b
4  e  5  2  1  2  b
5  f  4  3  0  4  b

mask = df.F == 'a'
df[['B','D']] = np.where(mask[:, None], df[['C','E']], df[['B','D']])
print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  a  7  7  5  5  a
1  b  8  8  3  3  a
2  c  9  9  6  6  a
3  d  5  4  7  9  b
4  e  5  2  1  2  b
5  f  4  3  0  4  b
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it with 2 `loc` statements, something along the lines of:

```
data.loc[data['qt_CNAE'] > 20, 'CNAEuse'] = data['CNAE']
data.loc[data['qt_CNAE'] > 20, 'CNAEuse_Cres'] = data['Crescimento_CNAE']
```

FYI, chained indexing as you have it (for example `data['CNAEuse'][i]`) is generally bad in `pandas`, and will often lead to setting with copy errors. Better to use `loc` operators or similar